# Employing NuSMV as a model checker in java

Tags: java, model-checking, nusmv

I'm trying to use NuSMV as a model checker in java. However, I'm not able to find the related JAR library online.

The only one I've found is provided on [here](http://haschemi.blogspot.com/2011/03/access-nusmv-from-java.html) for which the download link doesn't work anymore. Apparently, the library exists but the access link is not working.

Does anyone know how I can access NuSMV java API library or know of any alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working download link of **nusmv-tools** which is from the same author and includes the **Java** front-end you were talking about:

https://code.google.com/archive/a/eclipselabs.org/p/nusmv-tools/downloads

I haven't tested the library out, I just verified that it downloads.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked with some difficulties in finding the required libraries like nusmv.dll on https://code.google.com/archive/a/eclipselabs.org/p/nusmv-tools/source/default/source.

Comment: @Fred I guess one could just get the dll from the official NuSMV site, am I wrong?

Comment: I couldn't find it on their website. Moreover, you also need libnusmv.so and libnusmv.jnilib files.