# Access NuSMV from java

Tags: java, model-checking, nusmv

How can I access *NuSMV* as a model checker from java?
I want to use a library to call NuSMV and read a .smv file, check an `LTLSPEC` and return the satisfaction massage or counterexample as a result.
I have found [nusmv-tools](https://code.google.com/archive/a/eclipselabs.org/p/nusmv-tools), which is an Eclipse-based API. Since I work with IntelliJ, I cannot get the answer. I prefer a library, which is not dependent to any IDEs.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I hope I make it right.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531574/employing-nusmv-as-a-model-checker-in-java

Comment: I have checked it out formerly. It is **nusmv-tools**, that I gave the link to.